# MSVC swallows const from fundamental template parameter in variadic template methods using constexpr if

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-templates, if-constexpr

I have a problem that I'm almost certain is a MSVC bug, but maybe I'm missing something.

Here is a simplified version of the actual code:

```
template <typename... Args>
class InnerType {};

template <typename... Args>
class OuterType {
public:
    void foo1() {
        if constexpr (true) {
            bar(InnerType<Args...>());
        }
    }

    void foo2() {
        if (true) {
            bar(InnerType<Args...>());
        }
    }

    void bar(InnerType<Args...>) {}
};
```

As you can see, the only difference between `foo1()` and `foo2()` is the constexpr if. Here is what happens when I try to compile some tests in MSVC:

```
 OuterType<const bool> test1;
 test1.foo1(); // does not compile
 test1.foo2(); // compiles

 OuterType<bool> test2;
 test2.foo1(); // compiles
 test2.foo2(); // compiles
```

The error I get for `test1.foo1()` is:

```
error C2664: 'void OuterType<const bool>::bar(InnerType<const bool>)':
cannot convert argument 1 from 'InnerType<bool>' to 'InnerType<const bool>'
```

The same code compiles without a problem on Linux using GCC. Additionally, trying the same with a non-fundamental type works in MSVC as well:

```
 class SomeType {};

 OuterType<const SomeType> test;
 test.foo1(); // compiles
 test.foo2(); // compiles
```

So it seems that for some reason when using constexpr if and a const fundamental type as template parameter the `const` gets swallowed. The problem does not occur when it's not a variadic template.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/DBt9wQ) is a live example.

Am I right in assuming that it's a compiler bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[So it turned out to be a bug.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/292868/msvc-swallows-const-from-fundamental-template-para.html) For anyone experiencing the same issue, Microsoft said they will have it fixed in VS 15.8 Preview 4.